# Identifying duplicate values and copying to other cells using For Loops in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that has 3 sheets. Sheets 1 and 2 have 2 columns of information. column A is a unique identifier and column B is a currency value that may reoccur.

All the information in Sheet 1 will be repeated in Sheet 2, although sheet 2 will have additional information.

I need to loop through the unique identifier (Column A) in sheet 2, compare it to the information in sheet 1, and copy the unique information from sheet 2 to a range in sheet 3.

Im only learning the basics of VBA at the moment so there may be a better way to do this but i'm hoping to be able to expand the code to other workbooks.

Thanks For Helping.

```
        Sub Split_818s()
        Dim Ref As Long
        Dim Ref1 As Long
        Dim Amount As Long

        For Ref = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            For Ref1 = Range("B6") To Range("B100")   
        If (Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Ref).Value <> Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Ref).Value) Then
            Worksheets(“Sheet3”).Range(Ref1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2).Range(Ref).Value
          End If   
            Next Ref1
        Next Ref

        End Sub
```

Comment: In what way is the data on Sheet2 unique from Sheet1, are you comparing the IDs in column A.  your code appears to be comparing values in column B on Sheet1 with values in column A on Sheet1.

Comment: @Gordon The information in Column A in both sheets 1 & 2 is a unique userID. It's a report that is pulled twice daily. The second report contains all the same information as the first but additional information obtained throughout the day. I want the details to be copied from Sheet 2 Column A to Sheet 3 Column B

Answer (score 0):

I've put different syntaxes in there to show different approaches :

```
Sub Split_818s()
Dim wS1 As Worksheet
Dim wS2 As Worksheet
Dim wS3 As Worksheet
Dim Ref As Long
Dim Ref1 As Long
Dim Amount As Long

Set wS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wS2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set wS3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

wS3.Cells.Clear

For Ref = wS2.Range("A" & wS2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    For Ref1 = wS1.Range("B6").Row To wS1.Range("B100").Row
        If wS2.Range("A" & Ref).Value <> wS1.Cells(Ref1, 1).Value Then
            With wS3
                .Cells(.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = _
                        wS2.Range("A" & Ref).Value
            End With 'wS3
        End If
    Next Ref1
Next Ref

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Woohoo Arrays!!!!! This is a pretty simple piece of code. This will teach you alot once you start breaking the code down.

```
Private Sub this()
    Dim bringOver As Variant
    Dim bringOver2 As Variant
    Dim j As Long
    Dim i As Long
    i = 0
    j = 0
    bringOver = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    bringOver2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange
    For i = LBound(bringOver2, 1) To UBound(bringOver2, 1)
        If bringOver2(i, 1) = bringOver(i, 1) Then
            Debug.Print ; bringOver2(i, 1)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Sheet3.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = bringOver2(i, 3)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```