# Unique Values from a range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a code that looks at the opened worksheet (figWkst), looks in column F, and collects all the unique names, then adds one unique name at a time followed by the word "watcher" and a comma.

So, for example, if the unique names in column F are "Red, White, Blue, Green", then column R row n in the new worksheet will show "Red Watcher, White Watcher, Blue Watcher, Green Watcher." What I have now only displays in column R what column F row n displays.

I was thinking of using dictionaries but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you. Here is my code:

```
Sub Role()

'define variables
Dim RoleWkb As Workbook, figWkb As Workbook, RoleWkst As Worksheet, figWkst As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Long, a As Long, c As String, i As String, id As String, email As String, cityname As Variant

'open workbook
fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Role Workbook")
Set RoleWkb = Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath)
Set figWkb = ThisWorkbook
Set RoleWkst = RoleWkb.Sheets("UserProfile")
Set figWkst = figWkb.Worksheets("User Information")
cityname = InputBox("City name?")



'adding watcher group
aCell = figWkst.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For a = 12 To aCell
    If figWkst.Cells(a, 17) = "x" Or figWkst.Cells(a, 17) = "X" Then
        If RoleWkst.Cells(a - 1, 18) <> "" Then
            RoleWkst.Cells(a - 1, 18) = Trim(RoleWkst.Cells(a - 1, 18) & ", " & cityname & " " & figWkst.Cells(a, 6) & " Watcher")
        Else
            RoleWkst.Cells(a - 1, 18) = Trim(cityname & " " & figWkst.Cells(a, 6) & " Watcher")
        End If
    End If
Next a

End Sub
```

Comment: my answer here shows a simple way to test for duplicates while looping through a range/array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301589/identifying-duplicate-values-and-copying-to-other-cells-using-for-loops-in-vba-e/42301986#42301986

Answer (score 0):

How about this... although again it is a bit difficult to grasp or simulate your real situation...

```
Sub RoleModified()

'define variables
Dim RoleWkb As Workbook, figWkb As Workbook, RoleWkst As Worksheet, figWkst As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Long, a As Long, c As String, i As String, id As String, email As String, cityname As Variant

'added some variables
Dim vNames()                'to contain all the original names
Dim vUniqueNames()          'to collect unique ones
Dim vUniqueCount As Integer 'to count the unique ones
Dim vUnique As Boolean      'to mark that it was stored already

'open workbook
fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Role Workbook")
Set RoleWkb = ThisWorkbook
Set figWkb = ThisWorkbook
Set RoleWkst = RoleWkb.Sheets("UserProfile")
Set figWkst = figWkb.Worksheets("User Information")
cityname = InputBox("City name?", , "London")

'whatever way you can refer to where the names are, this worked for my 
'simulation...
figWkst.Select
vNames = Intersect(figWkst.UsedRange, Range("F:F"))

'set up the variables
ReDim vUniqueNames(1 To UBound(vNames, 1))
vUniqueCount = 0

'loop through all the names and take each one only once
For n = 1 To UBound(vNames, 1)
    vUnique = True
    'test it against those already stored
    For m = 1 To UBound(vNames, 1)
        If vUniqueNames(m) = vNames(n, 1) Then
            vUnique = False
        End If
    Next m
    'if not found, store it
    If vUnique Then
        vUniqueCount = vUniqueCount + 1
        vUniqueNames(vUniqueCount) = vNames(n, 1)
    End If
Next n

'placing unique names to the other sheet, meaning of x's missed
For n = 1 To vUniqueCount
    RoleWkst.Cells(10 + n, 18) = cityname & " " & _
    vUniqueNames(n) & " Watcher"
Next n

End Sub
```